# Rename dataset columns

Tags: r

I need to rename the rows of a dataset with a the value of a defined column:

```
   a  b  c 
1  d  e  f
2  g  h  i
3  j  k  l
```

has to become

```
   b  c  
d  e  f
g  h  i
j  k  l
```

Comment: That's generally a bad idea. It's better to work with column rather row names. Why do you *need* this?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I'm curious why this is generally a bad idea? I believe you, I just don't know.

Comment: @Jason For many reasons. Row names are messed up upon subsetting/reordering. They can't have duplicated values, they can be only of character class, it's harder to work with them in situation like joins or other data manipulation operations, etc.

Comment: Still if you want to do that, then you can use

rownames(df) <-  df$a "a" as your 1st column . After that you can just remove the first column .

Comment: @DavidArenburg, the thing is that i´m trying to plot with ggplot a dataset, and due to my experience with r i´m starting to think that for me is impossible...however i thought that a trasposition of the matrix could have helped me, but i was wrong.. and you were right